# Predictors of Poisson or Negative Binomial Regression of LMM or GLMM

Tags: poisson-regression, count-data

Just wondered if statistically it is wrong to have count data as a predictor (not confounders) of a  Poisson or Negative Binomial Regression of LMM or GLMM?

So far, I have seen continuous or categorical, or both.

Comment: You could use any type of variable as a predictor. The interpretation, though, will depend on the type of predictor you are using.